# Why, when I state listorder = m, m turns into listorder

Tags: list, python-3.x

When I use this code, for some reason instead of listorder becoming m, m becomes list order. http://pastebin.com/mfLx10e4
When I compile, I tried to print all of m

```
9
3
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 1]
[4, 1, 1]
[5, 1, 1]
[6, 1, 1]
[7, 1, 1]
[7, 1, 1]
[7, 1, 1]
5
```

But for some reason m is increasing when it should be staying the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You already did `m = listorder` further up. If you don't see why that's a problem, you should probably read up on [what assignment in Python actually does](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: So then how would you assign to copy data? I'm pretty new to python and I didn't know that's how assignment worked.

Comment: to make a copy of your list you can do `m = list( listorder )`